# SQL : Filter Column with row wise values

Tags: sql-server

T-SQL:
Below is my table on which i need to apply row wise filter on a col.
my criteria is that the Val should be : 0 AND (1 OR 1.1) AND 2

The original table is

```
name   val
aaa    0
aaa    1
aaa    1.1
aaa    2
bbb    0
bbb    2
ccc    0
ccc    1
ccc    2
```

The expected result will be

```
name   val
aaa     0
aaa     1
aaa     1.1
aaa     2
ccc     0
ccc     1
ccc     2
```

Could anyone suggest a solution. I am trying the Where clause but i am not able to give the conditions within the where clause.
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

The following will return all rows from the group when the conditions are satisfied:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(
      name varchar(10) NOT NULL
    , value varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @test(name, value)
VALUES
     ('aaa', '0')
    ,('aaa', '1')
    ,('aaa', '1.1')
    ,('aaa', '2')
    ,('bbb', '0')
    ,('bbb', '2')
    ,('ccc', '0')
    ,('ccc', '1')
    ,('ccc', '2');

SELECT a.name, a.value
FROM @test a
CROSS APPLY(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @test b WHERE b.name = a.name AND value IN('0', '2')) AS b(cnt)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @test b WHERE b.name = a.name AND value IN('1', '1.1')) AS c(cnt)
WHERE b.cnt = 2 AND c.cnt >= 1;
```

Comment: Why are you making the values varchar?

Comment: @Eric, just guessing at the data type. The sample data shows left-justified strings and no decimals for integer values.

Comment: fair enough, just keep in mind the OP may not have the best grasp of data types.  I'd hate to see numeric data represented as text in a production db  :)

Comment: Why cross apply and not simple left joins? `left join (select name, count(*) as cnt from @test where value IN('0', '2') group by name) c02 on c02.name=a.name`

Answer (score 0):

The 3 conditions are specified as a cte and join to your original table. The matching rows should be 3

```
; with 
-- your table
tbl as    
(
    select  name   = 'aaa',    val = 0    union all
    select  name   = 'aaa ',   val = 1    union all
    select  name   = 'aaa',    val = 1.1  union all
    select  name   = 'aaa',    val = 2    union all
    select  name   = 'bbb',    val = 0    union all
    select  name   = 'bbb',    val = 2    union all
    select  name   = 'ccc',    val = 0    union all
    select  name   = 'ccc',    val = 1    union all
    select  name   = 'ccc',    val = 2
),
--  your condition
val as
(
    select  val1 = 0, val2 = 0    union all
    select  val1 = 1, val2 = 1.1  union all
    select  val1 = 2, val2 = 2
),
cte_name as
(
    select  t.name
    from    tbl t
            inner join val v    on  t.val   = v.val1
                                or  t.val   = v.val2
    group by name
    having count(distinct v.val1) = 3   -- matching rows should be 3
) 
-- the query
select  t.*
from    tbl t
        inner join cte_name n   on  t.name  = n.name
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but given that the OP is having issues with a basic where clause, I think this is way too complicated.  I doubt the OP even knows what a CTE is.  Not trying to be rude, but I kept my answer stupid simple for a reason.

Comment: @Eric, you are right. This might be a bit over kill. But your solution actually does not produce the result that OP wants.  Because you only specify 2 condition `0 or 2` and `1 or 1.1`. What OP wanted is to fulfill all 3 conditions

Comment: that's not correct, an in clause includes all the values.  So its 0 and 2, not 0 or 2.

Comment: so for `in (0, 2)` condition, which row can satisfied both `0 and 2` ? try your query with my sample data or Dan's and see for yourself

Comment: just re-read the OPs question and realized the drop out of B. I misinterpreted the question.  So, you're correct that my solution was incorrect  : )

Answer (score 0):

One other version:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(
      name varchar(10) NOT NULL
    , value decimal(5,1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @test(name, value)
VALUES
     ('aaa', 0)
    ,('aaa', 1)
    ,('aaa', 1.1)
    ,('aaa', 2)
    ,('bbb', 0)
    ,('bbb', 2)
    ,('ccc', 0)
    ,('ccc', 1)
    ,('ccc', 2);

select a.name, a.value 
from @test a
join (
    select name, 
        sum(case when value IN(0,2) then 1 else 0 end) as c02, 
        sum(case when value IN(1,1.1) then 1 else 0 end) as c1 
    from @test group by name
    ) g on g.name=a.name and c02=2 and c1>=1
```